# 3rds and 6ths on guitar

Tags: theory, guitar

I've been working on 3rds and 6ths and struggled at first getting my head around the 6ths since they are, as played on guitar, really inverted 3rds.

Harmonizing in 3rds follows the diatonic chords, i.e. minor or flatted 3rds for the 2nd, 3rd, 6th, 7th. My question is, do we ever (can we?) harmonize using 6ths the same way?  So, the 2nd, 3rd, 6th, and 7th with *flatted 6ths* like they have flatted 3rds?  Unless I've done something wrong this doesn't quite work because the flat 6th of the 2nd isn't in the scale.  However, when played that way, it sounds more natural whereas when played sticking to the notes of the scale, thus no flat 6th over the 2nd it sounds a little "off" to my ear.  This may explain why all the 6th patterns I see are inversions.

Comment: 6ths on every instrument are inverted 3rds. And 3rds are inverted 6ths. That's how intervals work, not how guitars work.

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at the 3rds intervals.

C>E, F>A, G>B. All M3. When inverted, they become m6 (rule of 9, M>m)
E>C, A>F, B>G.

Now look at m3 intervals.

D>F, E>G, A>C, B>D. All m3. When inverted, they all become M6.

Now, 6th intervals.

C>A, F>D, G>E, all M6, and D>B, E>C, A>F, B>G, all m6.

Note, all notes are **diatonic**, within the scale/key. Like using a note on the the white keys, and the note two keys up for all the 3rds, and notes 5 keys apart for the 6ths, regardless of major or minor.

You *may* be thrown with the chord name m6, though. It's a confusing name - the *interval* isn't m6. The chord is a minor, with a 6th note added. Making actually a M6 interval with the root. That 6th is not from the natural minor scale, but the melodic minor, classical, rising.

Answer (score 1):

**Intervals of a diatonic 6th just use the notes in the *corresponding positions of the relative minor scale***. It's worth pointing out here that since you've already correctly identified that the 6ths are inversions of the 3rds, the pattern for the diatonic 6ths is the opposite of the minor scale's thirds pattern.

In **bold** below are the major 3rds for a major scale:

> **E** F G **A** **B** C D
>
> **C** D E **F** **G** A B

Here are those major thirds in **bold**, starting on the 6th scale degree (or the 1st scale degree of the relative minor):

> C D **E** F G **A** **B**
>
> A B **C** D E **F** **G**

Finally, here are the major 6ths in bold going up the major scale. Notice that we're just placing the minor scale over the major one:

> **A** **B** C **D** **E** F G
>
> **C** **D** E **F** **G** A B

This list of 6ths is just the previous thirds list flipped upside-down *(inverted)*, and the major 6ths are in the complementary positions compared to the major 3rds. The reason major and minor are flipped is because the inversion of any major interval is a minor one, and vice versa.

---

That's only good for *diatonic* intervals of a 6th, keep in mind. In music, there will be many harmonic situations where notes outside the diatonic set are chosen, and the topic of when to do so is both highly subjective and too lengthy to condense here.

Comment: Good info, thanks. Still curious about the b6 with the 2nd, harmonizing like 3rds, i.e. 2nd/3rd/6th/7th are minor.  I understand a minor 6th is determined by the 3rd not the 6th (1-b3-5-6) but playing 6ths, it has more of a minor tonality to me playing the b6 - like the 3rd/6th/7th have.  Playing 6ths sounds more natural to me this way  - the 2nd degree of the scale has a minor feel just like triads and 3rds.  I guess it's not truly harmonizing the scale in 6ths since the 6th of the 2nd is maj. but that's what sounds different or slightly off to me, that maj 6th with the 2nd.

Comment: @Jim you seem to be confusing intervals and chords.  A minor sixth above C natural is A flat.  This is not particularly relevant to the chord C-E flat-G-A.

Comment: Not confusing them, just trying to use chords to explain my question.  The m6 chord gets its minor tonality from the minor 3rd.  Remove that, like playing 6ths, and to my ear the minor 6th then provides that minor tonality.